# Phoenix equivalent of Rails.env.production?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm new to phoenix and elixier but the framework looks very interesting.
Currently i'm searching for an equivalent of Rails environment helpers.

> Rails.env.production?
>   Rails.env.staging?

is there a similar implementation in phoenix ?

Best Regards

Eric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function is not a part of the PhoenixFramework. Elixir's Mix supports three types of environment

`Mix.env` hold the current stage and give a result of `:dev`, `:test`, or `:prod`.
The develop option is used by default. On tests (`mix test`) the test environment will be automatically used.

This console call `MIX_ENV=prod mix compile` will compile the files in production environment.

See [Introduction to mix](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html#environments) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Fabi755 said you may also interact with the different environments through the Application module. There are functions like Application.get_env/2 which can fetch the same configuration based on the environment you are currently in (like let's say have a config for sending SMS to false in dev, but you have it to true in prod).

Ultimately the environments are not from Phoenix but from Elixir and the Mix tool.